# Remove Filter from table in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I want to display all table records when is there is filter field is empty or blank. Whenever there is value in USER Field, data is getting filtered based on value. Now I want to display all records if USER field is blank or empty.
Could you please help.
Below is the code

```
onSettingsSaveBtn: function (oEvent) {
    var oModel = this._oSettingsDialog.getModel("SettingsContext"),
    oData = oModel.getData(),
    user = oData.StoreID;
    var aTableSearchState = [];
    aTableSearchState = [new Filter("DeliveryStatus", "EQ", user)];
    var oBinding = this._oTable1.getBinding("items");
    this._oSettingsDialog.close();
    if (user === "") {
    }
    else {
    oBinding.filter(aTableSearchState,"Application");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give some example data, and what output you're hoping to achieve. (See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Comment: `oBinding.filter([])` should do the trick

Comment: oBinding.filter([]) not working.

Comment: I set the filter by statement oBinding.filter(aTableSearchState,"Application") and was trying remove filter when I used oBinding.filter(aTableSearchState); to set filter then oBinding.filter([]) is working .Thanku